# Mysql left outer join is taking too long time to respond from php

Tags: mysql

I have nearly 10000 records in my database. when the queries are not joined the query sent through PHP to mysql is working very fast. But when we join tables using left outer join it is very slow.

This my query.

```
    $sql = "select 
rollno,
stuname,
total,
ifnull(sum(fpaid),0) as feepaid,
total-COALESCE(sum(fpaid),0) as balance,
status,
comments,
category
from 
    (select
        studet.rollno as rollno,
        studet.stuname as stuname,
        studet.course as course,
        studet.branch as branch,
        studet.category as category,
        studet.year as year,
        studet.total as total,
        studet.status as status,
        studet.comments as comments,
        studet.academic as academic ,
        stufeeref.feepaid as fpaid
        from studet
        left outer join stufeeref
        on studet.rollno = stufeeref.rollno
        and studet.year = stufeeref.year
    ) as T
where  branch='$branch'
and year='$year'
and academic='$academic'
and course='$course'
group by rollno,year";
```

Please tell me how to  optimize my query.
 THanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add table definitions for `studet` and `stufeeref` tables? Use  `SHOW CREATE TABLE studet` to get the table definition.

Comment: Can you post the result of `show create table studet;` and `show create table stufeeref`? Looking at the tables will help identify if any indexes might help. Also, there may be a possibility of removing the sub-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the inline view query. It's not needed. It just causes MySQL do a lot more work.

The predicates in the outer query don't get pushed down into the inline view. You're essentially creating a copy of the table (a derived table), and the running a query against that. And that derived table doesn't have any indexes, it's doing a full scan of every row in the derived table.

```
SELECT s.rollno
     , s.stuname
     , s.total
     , IFNULL(SUM(r.fpaid),0) AS feepaid
     , s.total-COALESCE(SUM(r.fpaid),0) AS balance
     , s.status
     , s.comments
     , s.category
  FROM studet s
  LEFT
  JOIN stufeeref r
    ON r.rollno = s.rollno
   AND r.year   = s.year
 WHERE s.branch   = '$branch'
   AND s.year     = '$year'
   AND s.academic = '$academic'
   AND s.course   = '$course'
 GROUP BY s.rollno, s.year
```

For best performance, you'll want to have suitable indexes available.  For the `stufeeref` table, a covering index:

```
ON stufeeref (rollno, year, fpaid)
```

You want the rollno and year columns first, because of the join predicates; including the fpaid column means that MySQL can satisfy the query entirely from the index, without a need to retrieve blocks from the underlying table.

For `studet` table, the columns that have the equality predicates should be first.

```
ON studet (branch, year, academic, course)
```

(The order of those four columns in that index don't matter as much; the point is that MySQL can efficiently locate the rows by very quickly eliminating huge swaths of rows from being examined.)

---

Also, including variables in the SQL text is a SQL Injection vulnerability, if the values are not properly escaped, for example, using the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function.

For example:

```
 WHERE s.branch   = '". $mysqli->real_escape_string( $branch   ) ."'
   AND s.year     = '". $mysqli->real_escape_string( $year     ) ."'
   AND s.academic = '". $mysqli->real_escape_string( $academic ) ."'
   AND s.course   = '". $mysqli->real_escape_string( $course   ) ."'
```

Comment: Thank your very much sir. The query given by  you is working very  faster when compared to the posted query. Once again thank you very much.  Your query is excellent really once again congrats for your excellent brain.

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you using a subquery?

```
select s.rollno, s.stuname, s.total, ifnull(sum(sr.fpaid), 0) as feepaid,
       s.total-COALESCE(sum(sr.fpaid),0) as balance,
       s.status, s.comments, s.category
from studet s left outer join
     stufeeref sr
     on s.rollno = sr.rollno and s.year = sr.year
where s.branch='$branch' and s.year='$year' and s.academic='$academic' and s.course='$course'
group by s.rollno, s.year;
```

Now your query can take advantage of indexes.  The two indexes you want are `studet(branch, year, academic, course)` and `stufeeref(rollno, year, fpaid)`.

Comment: Thank you sir. The query is processing fast.  Thank you very much for your excellent support and for your excellency.